# Meteor Accounts-Base needed

Tags: meteor

I'm implementing custom user authentication in a Meteor application (so no use of accounts-ui). I have only done 'meteor add accounts-password' and registration/login are working as expected. In lots of tutorials, I also read they are doing a 'meteor add accounts-base' which is something I didn't do specifically, yet it is working.

Why would I need 'accounts-base'? For what functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

accounts-base is a dependency of accounts-password, so it's alteady included in your application, there's no need to add it separately. It provides the basic account concepts (`Meteor.users` collection, for instance) that accounts-password relied on.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected. I could not find this back in the documentation though (that accounts-base is automatically installed, it certainly does not show up in the packages folder)

Comment: Source code is helpful when documentation is not enough: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/package.js#L10